# WPF webbrowser play lottie animations?

Tags: wpf, lottie

Using .net framework 4.7, in a WPF application using the WebBrowser control, does this support displaying Lottie animations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The `WebBrowser` control uses the legacy Internet Explorer browser under the hood.

You should use the [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) control to display modern embedded web pages in a WPF application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,.  Yeah, that's pretty much the conclusion I've come to as well.  I am able to display lottie files using the WebView2 control but the differences between the WebBrowser and WebView2 controls, especially DOM access, would require some significant re-work in my project.  Long term, the switch would be worthwhile but for now, we'll probably take a different route.